# JNI how to call a C/C++ function in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

Searching for JNI, I've always found something like:

- Method in C/C++, call in Java
- Method in Java, call in C/C++

But never method in C/C++, call in C/C++ using JNI.

I ask that, because I have a 3rd party Java library, which has some C/C++ libraries, and I've always used Java to call them. And I would like now, to create some program using C instead of Java. Unfortunately they don't provide the any API in C/C++, only in Java.

Is it possible, if yes how can I try to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Calling existing C/C++ methods from C/C++ is just a matter of including the correct headers and ensuring you have the source or binaries to link against when compiling the C/C++ component. You *could* use JNI to call a custom Java method which then JNIs back into C/C++ in the third-party library, but if the library hasn't exposed uncompiled headers, chances are it's not intended to be accessed.

Comment: It is not intended to be accessed... I was hoping there were some methods to be "100%" in C/C++ instead of hoping through a method in Java to go back in C/C++. Which is silly. I will check if there is a way with the third-party developer to have some C/C++ apis...

Answer (score 0):

The JNI methods are always publicly exposed with an extern C signature.

This means that you could just link to the JNI dll directly if you have the method signature. (which you can easily get if you look at the Java class native method signature).

But you will have to make sure you give the method the environment it expects.
This means pass the "this" object and environment object.
You'll have to make sure that the class loader object has the right packages loaded in it. In most cases JNI code assumes the environment that called the method has the right class loader in it already (because the java method was called...).

And there's also an issue with local references that JNI code might assume are released automatically from the stack (which doesn't happen in C++ native threads).

Anyway, it would look like this:

```
//MyClass.java
class MyClass
{
 native void Blah();
}

//method signature, some header file:

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_Blah
        (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


//Call the function, C++ code


Java_MyClass_Blah(myEnv, myClassInstanve);
```